# Replace ' with \' in a string

Tags: python, replace

I have a string:

```
s = r"This is a 'test' string"
```

I am trying to replace `'` with `\'` so the string will look like below:

```
s = r"This is a \'test\' string"
```

I tried `s.replace("'","\'")` but there is no change in result. It remains the same.

Comment: What if the input string is `r"This is a 'test' string that already contains \'escaped quotes\'"`?

Comment: BTW: You should not use 'str' as a name. It is the name of a built-in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to escape the "\":

```
str.replace("'","\\'")
```

"\" is an escape sequence indicator, which, to be used as a normal char, has to be escaped (by) itself.

Comment: Refer this if you're seeing `\\\` in the output https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300917/replace-a-character-with-backslash-bug-python

Answer (score 8):

`"\'"` is still the same as `"'"` - you have to escape the backslash.

```
mystr = mystr.replace("'", "\\'")
```

Making it a raw string `r"\'"` would also work.

```
mystr = mystr.replace("'", r"\'")
```

Also note that you should never use `str` (or any other builtin name) as a variable name since it will overwrite the builtin, and could cause confusion later on when you try to use the builtin.

```
>>> mystr = "This is a 'test' string"
>>> print mystr.replace("'", "\\'")
This is a \'test\' string
>>> print mystr.replace("'", r"\'")
This is a \'test\' string
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> str = r"This is a 'test' string"
>>> print str
This is a 'test' string
>>> str.replace("'","\\'")
"This is a \\'test\\' string"
```

You need to escape the special character `\`