# Replace a character with backslash bug - Python

Tags: python, string, escaping

This feels like a bug to me.  I am unable to replace a character in a string with a single backslash:

```
>>>st = "a&b"
>>>st.replace('&','\\')
'a\\b'
```

I know that `'\'` isn't a legitimate string because the `\` escapes the last `'`.
However, I don't want the result to be `'a\\b'`; I want it to be `'a\b'`.  How is this possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are looking at the string *representation*, which is itself a valid Python string literal.

The `\\` is itself just *one* slash, but displayed as an escaped character to make the value a valid Python literal string. You can copy and paste that string back into Python and it'll produce the same value.

Use `print st.replace('&','\\')` to see the actual value being displayed, or test for the length of the resulting value:

```
>>> st = "a&b"
>>> print st.replace('&','\\')
a\b
>>> len(st.replace('&','\\'))
3
```